# How to make multiple predictions in neural network model with Keras

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have trained a `CNN` model with Keras using water temperature time series(minute-wise) and rainfall time series(daily)joint together as input data to predict bacteria level in water(label 1 being high risk, and label 0 being low risk). The two time series are filtered as 20 days of data prior to the sample collection date of water for bacteria testing.

Now I would like to use the model to make bacteria level prediction for 30 days in a row(so imagine how much bacteria is expected if a water sample is taken form that day at that particular place). How should I call the function to do this? Thanks